# Can Corda work under Ubuntu?

Tags: corda

I read the docs refer to Windows and Ubuntu for the installation of Corda. I rarely use Windows these days.

Can Corda work under Ubuntu?

I would prefer to install under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Corda runs fine where ever a JAR file can run.